# Flex Bubble Chart Bubble Scaling

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I am trying to Scale the bubbles within the bubble chart. The problem is, I have no control over the data coming in, and the radiusField values are usually below 0 ( no negative values ) with a max of maybe 2.

I created an ItemRenderer for the BubbleSeries, and tried adding a scaleX and scaleY value on the createChildren method, but nothing happens. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!
Michael

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is modify the axes to to have a different min/max value.  If the axes change their min/max, you can modify the scale of the information being shown.  You can set it statically or change it dynamically with the data provided.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_displayingdata_06.html